# Zip to longest length in Julia (like Python's zip_longest)

Tags: iterator, julia, zip

[`Base.Iterators.zip`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.zip) terminates at the shortest iterator, so here Carol/David/100 get dropped:

```py
julia> a = [1, 2]
julia> b = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "David"]
julia> c = [90, 85, 100]

julia> println.(zip(a, b, c))
# (1, "Alice", 90)
# (2, "Bob", 85)
```

Sometimes I want to `zip` to the longest iterator like Python's [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```py
>>> print(list(zip_longest(a, b, c)))
# [(1, 'Alice', 90),
#  (2, 'Bob', 85),
#  (None, 'Carol', 100),
#  (None, 'David', None)]
```

Is there a Julian version of `zip_longest`?

I've just been using a custom function to pad+zip by hand, but I wonder if I've missed something more built-in.

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/20499.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is kind of verbose, but you can do this:

```
julia> zip(
           Iterators.flatten((a, Iterators.repeated(nothing))),
           b,
           Iterators.flatten((c, Iterators.repeated(nothing))),
       ) |> collect
4-element Vector{Tuple{Any, String, Any}}:
 (1, "Alice", 90)
 (2, "Bob", 85)
 (nothing, "Carol", 100)
 (nothing, "David", nothing)
```

However, this requires knowing that `b` is the longest of the iterators. In order to handle any of the iterators being the shortest, you need to do something a bit more involved. This will do it:

```
function zip_longest(itrs...)
    itrs′ = map(itrs) do itr
        itr = Iterators.map(Some, itr)
        Iterators.flatten((itr, Iterators.repeated(nothing)))
    end
    itr = Iterators.takewhile(zip(itrs′...)) do t
        !all(isnothing, t)
    end
    Iterators.map(itr) do t
        map(x -> isnothing(x) ? x : something(x), t)
    end
end
```

This does what you want without knowing in advance which iterator is longest:

```
julia> zip_longest(a, b, c) |> collect
4-element Vector{Tuple{Any, String, Any}}:
 (1, "Alice", 90)
 (2, "Bob", 85)
 (nothing, "Carol", 100)
 (nothing, "David", nothing)
```

However, if I were contributing an implementation to IterTools, I would instead define a `ZipLongest` type an write out the explicit iteration logic (and provide show methods to show the same way `zip` does).

Comment: Thanks! Still new to Julia, so I'll have to take some time to digest this code. Maybe someone will take your last paragraph to heart and put together a comprehensive `zip_longest` PR.

Comment: There is a unmerged commit to IterTools.jl in 2020 for this exact function, which defined a Padded_it type instead of the ZipLongest type mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

If you are happy with a `Vector{Tuple}` similar to Python's output, you can use a comprehension like this:

```
zip_longest(xs...) = [get.(xs,i,nothing) for i in 1:maximum(length,xs)]
```

The idea is to use the default output of `get` to fill in the missing values.

```
a = [1, 2]
b = ["Alice", "Bob", "Carol", "David"]
c = [90, 85, 100]

zip_longest(a,b,c)
4-element Vector{Tuple{Any, String, Any}}:
 (1, "Alice", 90)
 (2, "Bob", 85)
 (nothing, "Carol", 100)
 (nothing, "David", nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of `get`. Very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

This approach seems to be fast(est):

```matlab
function zip_longest(iters...)
    filled = [[i; fill(nothing, maximum(length, iters) - length(i))] for i in iters]
    return zip(filled...)
end
```

It will [`fill`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.fill) the iterators to longest length and unpack them into [`zip`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.zip).

---

I'm still not fluent enough in Julia to understand the (dis)advantages of each version, but a few observations:

- Each version returns a different type:

  ```py
  typeof(stefan(a, b, c)) # Base.Generator{...}
  typeof(abo(a, b, c))    # Vector{...}
  typeof(mine(a, b, c))   # Base.Iterators.Zip{...}
  ```

  ```py
  typeof(collect(stefan(a, b, c)) # Vector{Tuple{Any, String, Any}}
  typeof(collect(abo(a, b, c))    # Vector{Tuple{Any, String, Any}} 
  typeof(collect(mine(a, b, c))   # Vector{Tuple{Union{Nothing, Int64}, Union{Nothing, String}, Union{Nothing, Int64}}}
  ```
- Stefan's generator version is fastest to construct:

  ```matlab
  using BenchmarkTools
  a = rand(1:100, 1000)
  b = rand(1:100, 1000000)
  c = rand(1:100, 100)
  d = rand(1:100, 10000)
  ```

  ```py
  @btime stefan(a, b, c, d) #1: 887.805 ns (12 allocations: 736 bytes)
  @btime abo(a, b, c, d)    #3: 115.956 ms (1000136 allocations: 68.82 MiB)
  @btime mine(a, b, c, d)   #2:   2.985 ms (18 allocations: 34.33 MiB)
  ```
- My fill+zip version seems fastest to collect/iterate:

  ```py
  @btime collect(stefan(a, b, c, d)) #3:   1.006  s (18011352 allocations: 638.40 MiB)
  @btime collect(abo(a, b, c, d))    #2: 121.395 ms (1000138 allocations: 76.45 MiB)
  @btime collect(mine(a, b, c, d))   #1:  79.415 ms (1000020 allocations: 57.38 MiB)
  ```

  ```py
  @btime for x in stefan(a, b, c, d) length(x) end #3: 639.829 ms (13010131 allocations: 444.45 MiB)
  @btime for x in abo(a, b, c, d) length(x) end    #2: 402.426 ms (4999116 allocations: 145.27 MiB)
  @btime for x in mine(a, b, c, d) length(x) end   #1: 340.051 ms (5000018 allocations: 202.64 MiB)
  ```

Comment: You should materialize the outputs to get a realistic timing. Do `@btime collect(zip_longest_stefan($a,$b,$c))` and `@btime zip_longest_abo($a,$b,$c)`, you should get something like `3.450 μs (92 allocations: 4.12 KiB)` and `1.510 μs (21 allocations: 960 bytes)`, respectively.

Comment: Hmm, then actually my fill+zip version seems fastest. I'm a bit surprised since both your version and mine create new vectors, which I assumed wasn't ideal.